# Possible to capture entire call stack from a jQuery call?

Tags: jquery

Admittedly, a strange question....but is it **possible** to somehow capture an entire javascript call stack from jQuery?  For example, let's say on page ready, I do a for each on every row in a table, and for a certain cell in each row, I want to change the row color based on this cell exceeding a certain value.

So, I'm wondering if it is possible to write this in jQuery, execute it, and somehow end up with an entire stack trace of the actual javascript that was executed?

### Update #1

Hmmm....this looks very similar to what I am hoping for (looks like it must be technically possible):
http://getfirebug.com/logging

**Stack traces**
*Just call console.trace() and Firebug will write a very informative stack trace to the console. Not only will it tell you which functions are on the stack, but it will include the value of each argument that was passed to each function. You can click the functions or objects to inspect them further.*

### Update #2

Ah of course, the question is: why?
How about this: javascript is allowed at my company, but jQuery is not.

### Conclusion

http://getfirebug.com/logging
or
http://blog.johnmckerrell.com/javascript-call-tracer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebug to inspect the call stack while a script is running. You can set breakpoints to break on specific conditions, or `console.log()` to log detailed information. Is that good enough for your needs?

**Update**

[javascript-call-tracer](http://blog.johnmckerrell.com/javascript-call-tracer/) looks promising. Keep in mind you will need to include non-minified versions of any jQuery files.

Also, reverse-engineering jQuery like this is going to be an awful lot of work over the long term. Especially when you encounter functions that have to be used multiple times, etc. Your best bet is to get whomever is calling the shots over there to reconsider, but if that is not possible then Good Luck...

Comment: I think that though would just essentially be stepping through in debug mode, would it not??  I was kinda hoping for something with much less manual intervention.

Comment: Well, are you just trying to debug your code, or are you planning to use the stack trace for another purpose?